# How can I find the error in value cannot be null

Tags: c#, xml

I already I have a c# code the contains an error **value cannot be null**.
*1st try*

```
if (Global.Publisher != "")
{
    opf.Descendants(GetNamespace(ref namespace3, "").GetName("metadata")).Descendants(namespace2 + "publisher").First().Value = Global.Publisher;
}
```

*2nd try*

```
if (Global.Publisher != "")
{
    opf.Descendants(GetNamespace(ref namespace3, "").GetName("metadata")).Descendants(namespace2 + "publisher").First().Value = Global.Publisher;
}
else
{
    opf.Descendants(GetNamespace(ref namespace3, "").GetName("metadata")).Descendants(namespace2 + "publisher").First().Value = null;
}
```

still i receive an error value cannot be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if (Global.Publisher != null && Global.Publisher != string.Empty)
```

Or, you can simply use

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Global.Publisher))
```

Answer (score 0):

You check is `Global.Publisher` is not empty u must check is not null `Global.Publisher != null`

try :

```
if (Global.Publisher != null && Global.Publisher != "" )
```

Comment: Or !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Global.Publisher)

Comment: I forgot.. effect of lack of sleep..  Thanks